# this.canvas.loadFromJson is not a function

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I have been trying to save a canvas setting into my localStorage system with this source:

```
saveToJson(){
let json = this.canvas.saveToJson();
console.log(json);
localStorage.setItem('canvasSettings',json);}
```

and trying to re-load the saved canvas ushing this code:

```
  loadJson(){
let savedCanvas= localStorage.getItem('canvasSettings');
console.log(savedCanvas);
this.canvas.loadFromJson(savedCanvas,()=>{console.log(savedCanvas)});


this.canvas.renderAll();}
```

unfortunately it keeps on giving me this error: this.canvas.loadFromJson is not a function

I'm using fabricjs v. 2.3.0 on npm also I have been following this tutorial : 
https://github.com/kevoj/angular-editor-fabric-js
kevoj's code works in my machine. this bothers me a lot. meanwhile kevoj is using 1.7.3

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo, it is [loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) . And to save canvas as json use  [toJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON)

Comment: I love you man! I have been banging my head over this issue for 6 hours!